# SharePoint o365 Custom Ribbon Action

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I have created a SP Hosted app.. then I added a Ribbon Custom Action and chose "Host Web"

I added the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<CustomAction Id="cautionIcon"
            Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
<CommandUIExtension>
  <!-- 
  Update the UI definitions below with the controls and the command actions
  that you want to enable for the custom action.
  -->
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition     Location="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.Groups._children">
      <Group
          Id="UploadLinkRibbonActionGroup"
          Sequence="80"
          Description="This group will contain the Button control"
          Title="Caution"
          Template="Ribbon.Templates.Flexible2">
        <Controls Id="UploadLinkControl">
          <Button
            Id="CautionButton"
            Command="UploadLinkButtonCommand"
           Image32by32="/sites/insightdeveloper/PublishingImages/mrT32.png"
            LabelText="Caution"
            TemplateAlias="o1"
            Sequence="10"/>
        </Controls>
      </Group>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
    <CommandUIDefinition
       Location="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.Scaling._children">
      <MaxSize
        Id="CustomEditRibbonActionsOneMaxSize"
        Sequence="15"
        GroupId="UploadLinkRibbonActionGroup"
        Size="LargeLarge"/>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler Command="UploadLinkButtonCommand"
                      CommandAction="~appWebUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}"/>
  </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension >
```

This does add a button to my ribbon.

The problem is I cannot invoke any custom JS as soon as I change the ~appWebUrl in the CommandAction= I get an error trying to deploy. "There were errors when validating the App Package".

I want to be able to add some JS on the command action "javascript:alert('hello');" but as soon as ~appWebUrl is missing I get the error.  I did not have this issue with SP 2010 this was very easy.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013, Custom action urls must start with "http:", "https:", "~appWebUrl" or "~remoteAppUrl". SharePoint 2010 it working fine. Check below:

"CustomAction cannot contain JavaScript: Any UrlActions or CommandActions must be a URL to navigate to. The URL can be parameterized with normal custom actions tokens in addition to the app-specific tokens." From here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220046.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: This sucks.... on Prem 2013 this is not an issue either. I can do the JS link.... that makes modifying the ribbon kind of useless for many scenarios.